# DatagramChannel.receive() seems to buffer packets

Tags: java, udp

I have a server sending UDP packets of 40 bytes every ~50 milliseconds to my client. The client receives these packets normally most of the time. However, every ~1-3 seconds no packets arrive for about ~500ms and then the following packets after that arrive at 0ms delay, as if the packets are buffered.

The following code is called in a separate thread with the sole purpose of receiving packets:

```
public synchronized int readUdp(DatagramChannel channel) throws IOException {
    InetSocketAddress sourceAddress = (InetSocketAddress) channel.receive(in);
    bytesRead = in.position();
    in.flip();

    // Read data out of buffer...
}
```

Here are some notes on my debugging findings:

- The server runs on the same computer as the client, but the communication is one way only (server -> client). All traffic goes from **127.0.0.1** to **127.0.0.1** and therefore there is no network interference.
- Using **RawCap** I have taken a look at the packets and their times and no oddities are visible, all delta times between packets in the capture are **~50ms**.
- The DatagramChannel is in **blocking** mode.
- The client is also connected to the server with **TCP** simultaneously, but no packets are actively sent on that channel.
- The buffer in which packets are stored is a ByteBuffer with a capacity of **1024 bytes**.
- The position of the buffer before calling channel.receive(in) is always **0**.
- The position of the buffer after calling channel.receive(in) is always **40.**
- The time after a packet being read and arriving at the same code section again is **~0ms**. Therefore, we can conclude that channel.receive(in) takes **~500ms** sometimes.
- The function **readUdp** is only called from one place.

A typical glitch looks like this:

```
Time: 49
Time: 51
Time: 49
Time: 51
Time: 307
Time: 0
Time: 0
Time: 0
Time: 0
Time: 1
Time: 41
Time: 51
Time: 49
```

I would appreciate it very much if anyone could examine this with a fresh pair of eyes. The only other close case I could find was here: http://www.coderanch.com/t/476539/Android/Mobile/UDP-DatagramSocket-receive-glitches. My code does not interact with Android in any way I should note though.

Comment: Whatever is going on here, it will be UDP, not Java, doing it.

Comment: Its going through loopback though, so there is not much that can happen in the UDP if it doesn't leave my computer. Also I have a unit test that sends UDP packets out every 50ms, and that seems to work fine, strangely enough. It seems there is something in my normal code that is disturbing the process.

Comment: Loopback is still UDP. Java doesn't buffer datagrams, it just calls `recv()` and friends. I've read strange reports about Windows 7 unduly buffering socket input, if that's your platform.

Comment: Yeah I didn't intend my title to mean that DatagramChannel.receive() buffers the packets, just that packets seem to get buffered and it becomes obvious when calling that function. I am on windows 8, however I have just done a bunch of profiling and it seems that excessive CPU use is the cause. When I turn off my renderer, the packets flow in normally.

Comment: You may not mean that but that is exactly what it says.